# Archive page URL for custom taxonomy and post type

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy

I created a custom post type and custom taxonomy.

I can access archive page for this custom post type, showing all entries for this type, but I am unable to get url for a specific taxonomy term.

When I access URL `http://example.com/chat/` I get `archive.php` template and all *chat* entries are listed, but when I access `http://example.com/chat-category/category-1` (**which is actually the URL shown in my wp-admin for this *chat-category***) I get a 404 and `archive.php` template wasn't even called. Also, creating template `taxonomy-chat-category.php` didn't work and I got also a 404.

Is there a correct URL for a specific *category/term* in a custom taxonomy?

The solution I can think of is adding a query var like `?chat-category=category-1` and modify the query in `archive.php` if this var is present, but I would rather prefer som nice and friendly URL solution.

This is my code:

```
    $labels = [
                    'name'              => _x( 'Categorías de chat', 'taxonomy general name', 'textdomain' ),
                    'singular_name'     => _x( 'Categoría de chat', 'taxonomy singular name', 'textdomain' ),
                    'search_items'      => __( 'Buscar categorías de chat', 'textdomain' ),
                    'all_items'         => __( 'Todas las categorías de chat', 'textdomain' ),
                    'parent_item'       => __( 'Categoría de chat padre', 'textdomain' ),
                    'parent_item_colon' => __( 'Categoría de chat padre:', 'textdomain' ),
                    'edit_item'         => __( 'Editar categoría de chat', 'textdomain' ),
                    'update_item'       => __( 'Actualizar categoría de chat', 'textdomain' ),
                    'add_new_item'      => __( 'Nueva categoría de chat', 'textdomain' ),
                    'new_item_name'     => __( 'Nuevo nombre de categoría de chat', 'textdomain' ),
                    'menu_name'         => __( 'Categoría de chat', 'textdomain' ),
               ];

    $args = [
        'hierarchical'      => true,
        'labels'            => $labels,
        'show_ui'           => true,
        'show_admin_column' => true,
        'query_var'         => true,
        'rewrite'           => array( 'slug' => 'chat-category' ),
        ];
 
    register_taxonomy('chat-category',  ['chat'], $args );
    unset($args);

    $args = [
                'labels' => ['name' => __( 'chats' ),
                             'singular_name' => __( 'chat' )
                            ],
                'can_export'          => true,
                'capability_type'     => 'post',
                'custom-fields'       => true,
                'exclude_from_search' => false,
                'has_archive'         => true,
                'hierarchical'        => true,
                'menu_icon'           => 'dashicons-video-alt2',
                'menu_position'       => 2,
                'public'              => true,
                'publicly_queryable'  => true,
                'taxonomies'          => ['chat-category'],
                'rewrite'             => ['slug' => 'chat'],
                'supports'            => [ 'author', 'title', 'editor', 'thumbnail', 'comments'],
                'show_ui'             => true,
                'show_in_menu'        => true,
                'show_in_nav_menus'   => true,
                'show_in_admin_bar'   => true,
            ];
    register_post_type( 'chat', $args);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, after a permalinks options reset (saving permalink options again) turns out that url `http://example.com/chat-category/category-1` is working correctly.